# Unable to start MySQL from the terminal

Tags: mysql, macos

I am quite new to the Macintosh, I have Mac OS 10.6 installed.

I downloaded the mysql-5.4.3-beta-osx10.5-x86.dmg file and installed all the files properly.

I have got [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) server started in system preferences.

Now I want to access MySQL from the terminal but I am unable to do it.

I have tried `mysql -u root`.

It shows "-bash: mysql: command not found".

How can I make it work?

Is there any tool like [phpMyAdmin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhpMyAdmin) for Mac?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you have a path problem in the current shell.  Some steps to check/do are:

- Can you get to the MySQL prompt from the installed location ?  Let's assume that you have installed MySQL in `/usr/local/mysql`.  Then if you change directory (`cd /usr/local/mysql/bin`) you should be able to execute the mysql command: `./mysql`
- Check the path settings via `env` command in your current shell.  What you are looking for is the value of `PATH` where you want to have something along the lines of:
  `PATH=/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin.....` with some reference to mysql's installled path
- Reset your current path to include `/usr/local/bin`.  This can be done in the instance of the current shell via `export PATH=/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH`
- Test that you can then access the mysql binary from any path on your system.

In terms of the tools for accessing MySQL you can take a look at:
-   [SequelPro](http://www.sequelpro.com/)
-   [MySQL Tools](http://www.mysql.com)

Answer (score 1):

To expand on lutz's (rather brusque) answer, if you look near the bottom of [the Mac OS X installation manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.4/en/mac-os-x-installation.html) you'll see the lines

```
alias mysql=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql
alias mysqladmin=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin
```

These are commands that tell your shell, `bash`, "when I type `mysql` I really mean to execute `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql`." You can add these commands to the end of the file `.bash_profile` in your user's home directory (using `echo` in conjunction with `>>~/.bash_profile` or similar) so that they get run every time you launch a shell.

Better yet, use the same file to change your `PATH` environment variable. Doing something like

```
export PATH="/usr/local/mysql/bin:${PATH}"
```

will tell the shell that any executable files found in that directory (like `mysql`, `mysqladmin`, and so forth) should be executed when you type just their names, rather than the full path.

Comment: If that answer doesn't seem clear enough, then you are probably new to UNIX-y shells in general, for this is `really` basic stuff that you will need to know.  Try reading one of the many tutorials out on the web on shell PATHs and shell aliases.

Comment: You can add the first line: alias mysql=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql to your .bash_profile by typing vi .bash_profile. Ultimately, this allows you to type "mysql" (without quotes) from the command line, and it will run the path mysql is stored on. If this doesn't work, the path mysql is stored on on your machine may be different. Read about vim commands here: http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/vimcheat.html

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I use MAMP. Just typed "/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql" instead of "mysql", and I got the problem resolved. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Open your terminal and type

```
> nano .bash_profile
```

add the followin line

```
export PATH="/usr/local/mysql/bin:${PATH}"
```

Save the file and re open the terminal, you should be able to write

```
mysql -u root -p
```

and login into mysql