# 'Login without a password is forbidden by configuration'

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, passwords, configuration-files

Sorry if this is long.  I have outlined the specific steps which brought me to the error.

*Background.*
 I installed apache, phpMyAdmin and MySQL to learn from tutorials.
Yesterday, I arrived to the point where we were beginning to use the MySQL database.

I somehow messed up (corrupted) my password settings.
I am conceptually confused about passwords for phpMyAdmin and passwords for mySql.

Originally I logged in just fine from the browser `/localhost/phpMyAdmin/`
     User: root
    Password: root

In config.inc.php this code was clearly associated:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'root';
```

Then this happened.
Inside the phpMyAdmin window,there is a tab called `USERS`

I took notice of all of the users and No Passwords were set so
I decided to set a password for 
    user: localhost
    Password: pass1234

Back at the browser I refreshed

localhost/phpMyAdmin/

Logged in
    User: root
    Password: pass1234
This Did Allow me to log in to phpMyAdmin and I could see the MySQL windows.

PLEASE take note of the above.
Now that I think about it.... I am even more confused because after this new password worked, I looked back in config.inc.php

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'root';
Had not changed to 
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'pass1234';
```

**Question**: are these two passwords associated ?

I then read somewhere that I should Not have set a password because it could cause problems later so I went back to the USERS tab and selected the radio button `'no password'`

BUT then when I refreshed the browser I was unable to log in.
Not with the original user: root password: root
not with the modified user: root password: pass1234

Not by just clicking 'go' which was what I expected to work since I selected 'no password'

I am very confused but I do not think that this is a deep level technical problem.

I now believe that settings above in `config.inc.php` are not the same thing as Changing this password setting from with phpMyAdmin and MySQL.

I have been troubleshooting with documentation and forums,
I really need some Conceptual Explanation of

What I did.
And 
How I can fix this.

I am completely stuck after many hours.

Thanks,

Here are some things that I tried.
Each time that I modified code, I restarted apachectl and I cleared my cookies.

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPasswordRoot'] = true;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPasswordRoot'] = false;
```

I Really Appreciate your Expertise, Insight and Clarification.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is not relation between those 2 password! 
Change this back to :`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'pass1234';` the old password 'root'
Cookies have nothing to do! as the service runs on your localhost.
Now restart your service and try again.

Comment: Thank you for responding. Please do not give up on this thread. You know what you are talking about....I can tell.  I later subsequently went back into the phpMyAdmin window and from there not config.inc.php, I chose 'no password'.  When I said pass1234, that was  an example. After all this, I do not even know what I used for a password although I may be able to guess.  But why would I need too if I chose 'no password' from within phpMyAdmin. I am still online for a few more hours USA east coast. Really thank you.

Comment: And I did try changing it back to root.  And I restarted apachectl. It did not work.

Comment: go to terminal cmd line and type this in : mysql -uroot -proot

Comment: I just want to be completely certain where I should use this command.  I need to get into the MySQL directory but there are more than one. Thanks.

Comment: does't matter ! just open cmd line and run it ! see the output

Comment: we are doing this to check that the user has access to the database! using the mysql client

Comment: I really am not a novice programmer but I am really unfamiliar using MySQL command line. In typed mysql uroot -proof at the prompt.  Error. -bash: MySQL: command not found.

Comment: is ok ! not a big deal just go to the START button and type 'cmd' the cmd line will popup - type the cmd i had send you and see the result !

Comment: On a Mac.   If I were on a pc I do know what you are talking about.

Comment: ok , so on the mac follow this link to see how is done :http://www.wikihow.com/Get-to-the-Command-Line-on-a-Mac

Comment: I found this http://commandlinemac.blogspot.com/2008/12/mysql.html and I get this -sort of. We just crossed posts.  So using the command mysql and then options should work.  I will look at your link now.thanks

Comment: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-command-not-found-error-and-how-to-get-rid-of-it/ has an explanation which is close but when I type echo $PATH I get a long path which seems legitamate /usr/bin:/bin/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin   But whereis MySQL returns nothing.

Comment: Still working on this but for the sake if others I found this and it is clearing up a lot.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826193/unable-to-start-mysql-from-the-terminal